# Expectation of number of trails till $r$ successes.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, proof-verification, binomial-distribution

Let $X$ be the number of Bernoulli trails till $r$ successes with probability $p$ (including the last one). Find $\mathbb{E}(X)$.

My attempt:

$$P(X<r) = 0$$
$$P(X=r) = p^r$$
$$P(X=r+s) = p^r(1-p)^s$$
$$\mathbb{E}(X) = p^r\sum_{n=r}^{\infty}n(p-1)^{n-r}$$

I think I can simplify this using the geometric series but does this make sense as an answer?

Comment: We have $\Pr(X=n)=p\binom{n-1}{r-1}p^{r-1}(1-p)^{n-r}$. So there is a binomial coefficient missing in your expression. Then for the expectation we can multiply by $n$ as you did and add up. The expression can then be simplified greatly. This is not the cleanest way to find the mean.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Would I eventually end up at $\mathbb{E}=np$? If not what would be the better way to find the expectation? EDIT: I see that I confused two random variables. $np$ would be the expectation of the successes obtained. I still would like to know the best way to find the expectation I need.

Comment: You will end up with $\frac{r}{p}$. Do you already know the mean of a random variable with geometric distribution?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes that would be 1/p for the expectation of the trails one ends up performing. But how are you connecting the two?

Comment: I will write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct expression for $\Pr(X=n)$ has been dealt with in comments. From that expression one can, by manipulation, find $E(X)$. But there are easier ways.

Let $X_1$ be the number of trials until the first success. Let $X_2$ be the number of trials from (but not including) the first success to (and including) the second success. Similarly, define $X_3,\dots,X_r$.

Then $X=X_1+X_2+\cdots +X_r$, so by the linearity of expectation we have $E(X)=E(X_1)+E(X_2)+\cdots+E(X_r)$.

Each of the $X_i$ has geometric distribution with parameter $p$, so $E(X_i)=\frac{1}{p}$ for all $i$. It follows that $E(X)=\frac{r}{p}$.

Comment: >so by the linearity of expectation ok that is all I wanted to clear things up. I'm a bit wonky on the theory. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.  The expectation of a sum of random variables is the sum of the expectations.